# AIX telnet from remote

Tags: aix

Although i can telnet the AIX server from the local network , i cant get access to it via the internet.. Itsnt a firewall/router issue 100% as trying on other computers worked great...
AIX is version 4.5 i think... around 1995.
Any ideas guys??

Comment: Do you have `/etc/hosts.allow` or `/etc/hosts.deny` files?

Comment: maybe ... but didnt know what to write and where!

Comment: possibly tcpwrappers has been enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess AIX 4.3.3 (it then went to 5.x)
Do a netstat -rn and check for a default route.
You can probably telnet in on the local LAN because the ethernet interface is on the same network.  However when you try it from the internet, unless the default route is correct, then it wont know how to route packets back to you.

Comment: you mean that it doesnt have a gateway set? I saw that it has only ip set and nothing else even mask is absent...

Comment: try something like "ping www.google.com" and see if it knows what to do with it